# How to share a Calendar Event via a ShareLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, eventkit, sharelink

I am trying to create a `TransferRepresentation` with `UTType.calendarEvent` to make a `struct` `Transferable` and usable in a `ShareLink`

```
ShareLink(item: event, preview: SharePreview(event.name))
```

I tried:

1. Creating a VCalendar-String and converting it to `Data`

```
struct Event: Transferable, ... {
    ...
    let uuid: String
    let name: String
    
    var isoDate: String { ... }

    ...
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .calendarEvent) { event in
            return "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:\(event.uuid)\nDTSTAMP:\(event.isoDate)\nDTSTART:\(event.isoDate)\nDTEND:\(event.isoDate)\nSUMMARY:\(event.name)\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR".data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
        }
    }
}
```

`isoDate` is in the format `yyyymmddThhmmssZ`
The ShareLink works, but only shows AirDrop and trying to share via AirDrop always fails. But if I change the `exportedContentType` to `UTType.plainText` and rename the exported `.txt` file to `.ics` that File works and can be imported in the Calendar.

2. Creating an `EKEvent` and converting it to `Data`

```
struct Event: Transferable, ... {
    ...
    let uuid: String
    let name: String
    
    var isoDate: String { ... }

    ...
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(exportedContentType: .calendarEvent) { event in
            let ekevent = EKEvent()
            ...
            return ...
        }
    }
}
```

But neither `ekevent as Data` nor `Data(ekevent)` works

3. Directly using an `EKEvent` in the `ShareLink`, but `EKEvent` is not `Transferable`